# Where did Edom pursue his brother with a sword as recorded in Amos 1:11?

Tags: genesis, history, jacob, amos

Amos 1:11 NKJV

> 11 Thus says the LORD:  “For three transgressions of Edom, and for four,  I will not turn away its  punishment,  Because he pursued his brother with the sword,  And cast off all pity;  His anger tore perpetually,  And he kept his wrath forever.

After having duped his brother of the inheritance(Genesis 27:1-47) Jacob fled to his uncle Laban.

There is no record of Esau ever pursuing him with a sword.After a couple of years Jacob returned and was met by the same brother.

There is no record of any reprisals again here

To which event does this text refer?

Comment: there is no biblical record but see my answer for a second c. bce record that gives the place as Hebron.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Bible often uses the name of a progenitor as the name for the entire race.  This is a perfect example.  Other cases include "Moab", "Ammon", and many more.  Even the name "Israel" is only another name for the man Jacob as well as the nation that came from Jacob.

The Bible records a number of times when Edom (Esau) clashed in war with Israel (Jacob).  See Numbers 20:14-21 (compare Deut 2:2-8); 2 Kings 8:20-22; 2 Chron 28:16, 17.

Thus, it is clear that Amos 1:11 is discussing two nations at war rather than the individual, original brothers.

Comment: You are right that Amos is discussing the nations rather than the individuals. But it is still not clear what event exactly. Numbers 20:14-21 happened hunderds of years before Amos; 2 Kings 8:20-22 says that Edom broke out of the reign of Judah - not that Edom chased Judah with a sword; and 2 Chron 28:17 happened at the days of Ahaz, who lived two generations after Uziya who lived at the time of Amos.

Comment: Moreover: Amos 1:1 says that Amos spoke "two years before the earthquake", which happened at the last year of Uziya, king of Judah (see Isaiah 6). During that time, both kingdoms - Judah and Israel - were very strong, and Edom was probably occupied by Judah (it was struck by Amatzya: see 2 Kings 14:7). So it is again unclear, when exactly did Edom chase Israel with a sword?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to suggest that this is about the period of local turmoil immediately after the fall of Jerusalem to the Babylonians.

During this time, surrounding nations were taking advantage of the defenceless state of the remaining inhabitants of Judah (as Jeremiah ch40 shows, not everybody went into exile). This ruthless exploitation is documented in the complaints of several prophets. Obadiah is one long complaint about what the Edomites were doing, including "cutting off the fugitives" (v14). See also Ezekiel; "acted revengefully against the house of Judah" (ch25 v12) and "You gave over the people of Israel to the power of the sword in the time of their calamity"(ch35 v5). In the middle of this turmoil, the city of Tyre "sold the people of Judah and Jerusalem to the Greeks, removing them far from their own border" (Joel ch3 v6), thus helping to inauguarate the Dispersion of the Jews. That would explain the indignant attack on Tyre in Ezekiel from ch26.

I suggest that the section in Amos ch1 which runs from v6 to v12 is about this period of anarchy, when the helpless survving Jews were being robbed and enslaved. The people of Gaza "carried into exile a whole people to deliver them up to Edom" (v6). Tyre did the same thing (v9). As for Edom, he "pursued his brother with the sword and cast off all pity" (v11). In fact this was the period when Edom was energetically shifting the southern boundary of Judah northwards, to the line where we find it in Roman times.

Unfortunately this theory, however much sense it makes to a student of history, involves identifying that section as a later addition to the book of Amos, which belongs to a much earlier time, so it won't be everybody's cup of tea.

Comment: In Amos 1:5, it is said that Aram will be exiled to Kir. This was done by Tiglat Pileser, king of Assyria, who lived long before the Babylonians.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's why my suggested "later" section does not begin until v6, though it continues the pattern.

Comment: Interestingly, the traditional Jewish commentaries also relate these prophecies to the fall of Jerusalem to the Babylonians, even though they agree that all these prophecies were done by Amos.

Answer (score 2):

### Hebron

I do not dispute that Amos could have been speaking of Edom collectively. However, a Second-temple period source, namely [Jubilees 37:15](https://sacred-texts.com/bib/jub/jub72.htm), describes Esau and his Edomite army (4,000 men) quite specifically as pursuing Jacob to Hebron.

> The men of Hebron sent to him (Jacob)
> saying, "Behold thy brother hath come against thee, to fight thee,
> with four thousand girt with the sword, and they carry shields and
> weapons." For they loved Jacob more than Esau, so they told him; for
> Jacob was a more liberal and merciful man...

The [Book of Jubilees](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8944-jubilees-book-of) was apparently compiled from older legends by "the Pharisaic school of the time of John Hyrcanus, in whose reign it was written, between 135 and 105 B.C." It is not certain if this story dates back through the oral tradition to the time of Amos, but Hebron is definitely worthy of consideration. This account also deals both with Esau and his soldiers. Thus both Edom collectively and Esau individually pursued the patriarch Jacob with the sword at Hebron, according to the Book of Jubilees.

Comment: OK, but this happened over 1000 years before Amos. And since then, the descendants of Esau have been punished severely, e.g. by King David occupying Edom. So why would Amos mention this historic event as an unforgiveable crime of Edom?

Comment: I'm just reporting what the Book of Jubilees says not my personal opinion. As I mentioned, we can't know if this legend is goes back to Amos' time and I'm not saying it really happened this way.  But there's a strain of ancient Jewish thought that portrays Esau as evil to the core. See the section [His Vicious Character](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5846-esau) in the Jewish Encyclopedia article. As you surely know, rabbinical opinions are far from unanimous.

Answer (score 1):

The prophet, Amos, was contemporary with the prophets Hosea and Isaiah during the 8th century BCE, which was more than 1,100 years after Jacob/Israel and Esau. Genesis 27:39,40 (ESV) states in part

> <sup>**39**</sup> Then Isaac his father answered and said to him: ... <sup>**40**</sup> “By your **sword** you shall live, and you shall serve your brother; but when you grow restless you shall break his yoke from your neck.”

This was a prophecy pertaining to *both* Esau and the people group he later founded, the Edomites. We know this was prophetic because historically, the Edomites constantly attacked Israel. As a result, Saul and David fought wars against the Edomites, and King David conquered them only for them to “break the yoke” of Israel after the reign of Solomon.

In Genesis 27:41-43 (ESV), we read:

> <sup>**41**</sup> Now Esau hated Jacob because of the blessing with which his father had blessed him, and Esau said to himself, “The days of mourning for my father are approaching; then **I will kill my brother Jacob**.” <sup>**42**</sup> But the words of Esau her older son were told to Rebekah. So she sent and called Jacob her younger son and said to him, “Behold, your brother Esau comforts himself about you by planning to kill you. <sup>**43**</sup> Now therefore, my son, obey my voice. **Arise, flee to Laban my brother** in Haran.

While Esau and Jacob were eventually reconciled, Jacob obviously distrusted Esau, probably for good reason.

The Edomites were later called Idumaeans (from the Greek name for the region, *Idoumaia*). One Idumaean converted to Judaism and, with the support of Octavian, Mark Antony, and the Roman army, became “King Herod the Great,” who had the male babies and toddlers in Bethlehem slaughtered in his attempt to kill the promised Messiah and prophesied King of Israel.

Comment: So you say that Amos refers to Herod? But Herod lived hundreds of years after Amos.

Comment: Yes, indeed! This is why I wrote "This [Jacob's blessing on Esau] was a prophecy pertaining to both Esau and the people group he later founded, the Edomites." The prophets if Israel commonly wrote about future events, both short term and long term, to establish their credibility (and not get stoned for being a false prophet). Consider Daniel's prophecies concerning Messiah and the destruction of the second Temple as another example.

Comment: Of course, the prophets wrote about future events. But here the prophet is accusing Edom for a crime they have not done yet, which is quite unusual.

Comment: So, how else would one interpret "I will kill my brother Jacob" as spoken by Esau? Isaac told Esau that he would live "by the sword." Rebekah warned Jacob to flee, so it seems she certainly took Esau's threat seriously. I believe references to "the sword" in the *Tanakh* can refer to warfare in general. Thus, there's an implication that Esau planned to kill Jacob with "the sword" (or with whatever he killed and butchered the game he prepared for Isaac) and that Jacob fled. There's no historical doubt that Esau's descendants **pursued** Jacob's descendants with "the sword" as Amos wrote.

Comment: Or perhaps I misunderstood. Are you pointing out that merely *pursuing* someone with "the sword" itself is not a crime because Esau did not actually kill Jacob?

Comment: In this case, Amos is accusing Esau for a crime he has done hundreds of  years in the past, which was avenged many times later (e.g. when King David occupied Edom, he already took revenge for Esau's pursuit of Jacob)

Comment: In your experience, does avenging a crime undo the original crime? Does it restore the perpetrator to his original place of trust and respect? What's the usual outcome in history?

Comment: If Edom was already avenged for their crimes, why punish them again?

Comment: Because vengeance doesn't *undo* a crime--as is obvious from any study of history. Consider Deuteronomy 32:35 (ESV), "[The Lord says] ‘**Vengeance is Mine**, and retribution, in due time their foot will slip; For the day of their calamity is near, And the impending things are hastening upon them.’"